# Drag and Drop in iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make web app that will allow user to drag div's in iframe element.

This is my current code in index.html :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function onDrag(event){
        event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', 'Some content');
    }
</script>
<div id="items">
    <ul>
        <li><div draggable="true" ondrag="onDrag(event)">Content1</div></li>
        <li><div draggable="true" ondrag="onDrag(event)">Content2</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<iframe id="box" src="box.html">
</iframe>
```

And here is my code from box.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>    
        function onDrop(event){
            event.target.innerHTML += event.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
            alert('Ok!');
        }
        function onDragOver(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body ondragover="onDragOver(event)" ondrop="onDrop(event)">
</body>
</html>
```

Drag works, and I even get that alert from onDrop function, but the `event.dataTransfer.getData('Text')` is returning empty string, and I don't know why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set drag data in the `dragstart` event, not the `drag` event: http://jsfiddle.net/SVtzK/1/.